# Is “まだ物が揃わず” a clause of “家がまだ物が揃わず不便ですが”?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Context:

家**が**まだ物**が**揃わず不便ですが、ネットで買えるので便利ですね！

"が" marks a subject, and a sentence has only one subject.

There are two "が" in this sentence, is it because "まだ物が揃わず" is a clause? Does it modify "家"?

Can it be rewritten to "“まだ物が揃わず家が不便です"?

Is "揃わず" a special form of "揃わない" when it modifies something?

Comment: Kind of related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44439/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 「まだ物が揃わず」 is a clause that adds a reason and modifies the na-adjective 不便です. Gramatically, ず is a 連体形 form of the auxiliary verb ぬ (nagation). V-ず sometimes replace V-なくて, especially in written language.

https://web.mit.edu/kakikotoba/renyoo-chuushi.html