# I don't understand the use of the って contraction on this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles

While looking through some example sentences, I found one where I couldn't completely understand the use of the って particle ([Here is the full context if needed](https://guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/favors)):

> いいことを教えてあげよう。お前もいつか子供が出来たらこんなのも出来るんだ**って**

And this is the translation that is provided by the source:

> Let me (give you favor of) teaching good thing. That when you have
> kids one day, you can do this kind of thing.

I know that って in this case is a contraction for と言う and that it is generally used to quote someone or to use indirect speech, but I don't see that working here. I also read that you can use って on casual speech to emphasize what you are saying or show your frustration, but I am not sure that this the case for this piece of dialogue.

Answer (score 3):

って in this case is an colloquial version of と, not という. 教える takes a と-clause just as 考える and 言う do.

- これは本だ**と**言った。
  これは本だ**って**言った。(colloquial)
  I said this is a book.
- これは本だ**と**教えた。
  これは本だ**って**教えた。(colloquial)
  I taught [someone] that this is a book.

In your example, the word order is a little unusual (the verb comes first, somewhat like in English), but the basic meaning stays the same. See: [Does word order change the meaning of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19433/5010) and [What does と mean in 「ここにおいで」と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38645/5010)

Comment: Oh, so the と in this case makes reference to the "teaching". I thought that was a possibility, but is nice to have some confirmation.