# Intransitive verb connects with a transitive verb via Te Form

Tags: grammar

I have learnt that a noun that is preceding an intransitive verb should go with the GA particle (it is a subject). And a noun that is preceding a transitive verb then it should be used with the WO particle (it is an object).

However, I have also learnt that verbs in Japanese can be connected with TE FORM. So can we connect an intransitive verb with a transitive verb?

If it is yes, then how can we decide which particle to use (GA or WO)?
Because in this sentence the Noun is the subject for a verb but also the object for the other?

The pattern is just like this:

NOUN (GA/WO) V1 TE + V2 TE +...
In which V(n) can be a transitive verb or intransitive verb.

Could you please give me some examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel you are a little confused because you have seen some over-simplified explanation about transitive verbs... Perhaps it's best to learn from examples.

- 私は<sup>S</sup> 寝ます<sup>Vi</sup>。
  I<sup>S</sup> sleep<sup>Vi</sup>.
- 私は<sup>S</sup> 起きます<sup>Vi</sup>。
  I<sup>S</sup> wake<sup>Vi</sup> (up).
- 私は<sup>S</sup> シャワーを<sup>O</sup> 浴びます<sup>Vt</sup>。
  I<sup>S</sup> take<sup>Vt</sup> a shower<sup>O</sup>.
- 私は<sup>S</sup> 朝食を<sup>O</sup> 食べます<sup>Vt</sup>。
  I<sup>S</sup> eat<sup>Vt</sup> breakfast<sup>O</sup>.

Using a te-from to connect two verbs...

- 私は<sup>S</sup> シャワーを<sup>O1</sup> **浴びて**<sup>Vt1*</sup> 寝ます<sup>Vi2</sup>。
  I<sup>S</sup> take<sup>Vt1</sup> a shower<sup>O1</sup> **and** (then) sleep<sup>Vi2</sup>.
- 私は<sup>S</sup> **起きて**<sup>Vi1*</sup> シャワーを<sup>O2</sup> 浴びます<sup>Vt2</sup>。
  I<sup>S</sup> wake<sup>Vi1</sup> (up) **and** (then) take<sup>Vt2</sup> a shower<sup>O2</sup>.
- 私は<sup>S</sup> シャワーを<sup>O1</sup> **浴びて**<sup>Vt1*</sup> 朝食を<sup>O2</sup> 食べます<sup>Vt2</sup>。
  I<sup>S</sup> take<sup>Vt1</sup> a shower<sup>O1</sup> **and** eat<sup>Vt2</sup> breakfast<sup>O2</sup>.

(S: subject, Vi: intransitive verb, Vt: transitive verb, O: object, *: te-form)

So, aside from the obvious difference in word order (S-O-V vs S-V-O), I hope you can see there is not much difference.

Just like English verbs, every Japanese verb has a corresponding subject, which is marked by が (or は) but may be omitted. A transitive verb *additionally* takes an object, which is marked by を. (In other words, a transitive verb takes two [arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics)), while an intransitive verb take only one.)

Also note that シャワーを私は浴びます is still a valid Japanese sentence, although it sounds clumsy in a simple case like this. See: [Does word order change the meaning of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19433/5010)

Comment: Thank you, naruto. I 've got a simple sentence, which is 私は彼が好きで彼を尊敬している。In which you can see that 彼 appears twice, once with ga, and once with wo. I dont know if my sentence is right or not, and can we group the word 彼 ?

Comment: @RenChen Your sentence is perfectly correct. It's not possible to "group" those 彼 because they are used with different particles. But it's possible to "omit" the second 彼(を) because it can be inferred form the context of the first half of the sentence (i.e., 私は彼が好きで尊敬している).