# Can this sentence be rephrased like this?

Tags: nuances, reading-comprehension, word-order

I’ve come across this sentence

> 「それに考えてないよ高木さんのことなんて…」

Which translates to

> “Moreover why would I be thinking about Takagi-san”

While the literal translation would probably be something like

> “Moreover I haven’t been thinking about Takagi-san or Takagi-san-like things, you know”

And I’ve been wondering if it could be rephrased as follows

> 「それに高木さんのことなんて考えてないよ…」

I think that the rephrasing makes the speaker seem more sure of himself in comparison to the original sentence but is there any other difference in meaning or nuance that I may have inadvertently induced by this reordering? Does it sound as natural as the original? Is it even valid? Would it still be translated the same way?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it can be rephrased like that, it still means the same, but I don't think your translations are good. Where did you get those translations from?

Comment: @GuiImamura The first translation is taken straight from the anime (with me adding the "moreover" since the original ignored それに). It might be fan sub but I'm not sure. The "literal" translation is my own. How would you translate it?

Comment: It would be close to your own translation, but removing the "Takagi-san-like things" and changjng the verb tense from "I haven't been thinking" to "I'm not thinking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. それに考えてないよ高木さんのことなんて…
2. それに高木さんのことなんて考えてないよ…

The two sentences are the same except for the word order, and their meanings are also identical. Sentence 2 is the standard in terms of word order, and Sentence 1 is an "inverted" sentence (倒置/[hyperbaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton)). In reality, a sentence like 1 is is very common in casual speech even when a rhetorical effect is not intended. See: [Does word order change the meaning of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19433/5010)

But note that なんて never means "or something/someone like that". Maybe you thought など and なんて have exactly the same meaning? なんて does not have a meaning of "et cetera", but it is used to add a nuance of making light of the word that comes before it.

Comment: Thanks. So would it be alright to say that なんて in this case is translated as "why would"? As for なんて I was going by [jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6)

Comment: @UriGreenberg If this なんて *must* to be translated, it would be "someone like you, Takagi", not "Takagi or someone like her".